# Translating an array of chars into an array of numbers in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So, what I need to do is translate an array of chars into an array of numbers.

I know this sounds like an odd request, but here's what I've been trying to do:

Have an array like this:

```
charArray[0] = e;
charArray[1] = b;
charArray[2] = p;
```

and have it translatated into:

```
numArray[0] = 5;
numArray[1] = 2;
numArray[2] = 16;
```

So it would translate the char into it's position in the alphabet (eg. "a" is the 1st letter, "b" is the 2nd, etc)

What's the best way of doing this? I was going to attempt to do it one by one, but then realized I would have way too many lines of code, it would just be tons of nested if statements, and I figured there's probably some better way to do it.

(My way was going to be `if charArray[0] = a then numArray[0] = 1`, and go through every single letter like that, until you get to `if charArray[0] = z then numArray[0] = 26`, but that would require 26 different if statements PER CHAR in the char array, which would be a horrible way of doing it in my opinion, because my char array is extremely long.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a trick For each index `i`:

```
numArray[i] = charArray[i] - 'a' + 1;
```

A more "by the book" way of doing it is:

```
final String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
. . .
numArray[i] = letters.indexOf(charArray[i]) + 1;
```

Then any positions `i` such that `charAray[i]` is not a lower-case letter will end up as 0 in `numArray[i]`. With the trick, the value of `numArray[i]` will be something unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply:

`numArray[i] = charArray[i] - 'a' + 1;`

**Explanation:**

Looking at the *[ascci table](http://www.asciitable.com/)* you'll see the *decimal value* of each *char*.

`a` has the *decimal value* of 97. So you remove 97 from it and add 1. You get 1.

The same for `b`...`z`, removing 97 (`a`) from 98 (`b`) will be 1, and you add 1 to get 2.. and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Assume all characters are lowercase, you can write:

```
numArray[0]  = (charArray[0] - 'a' + 1);
```

If you have lowercase and uppercase, you can use an if statement like:

```
if (charArray[0] >= 'A' && charArray[0] <= 'Z') {
  numArray[0]  = (charArray[0] - 'A' + 1);
} else {
  numArray[0]  = (charArray[0] - 'a' + 1);
}
```